# How to create a pre-trained weight model similar to Imagenet or Noisy-student?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to create a pre-trained weight model file that could be used for initialization of a model similar to imagenet pre-trained weight file or that of noisy-student.

I have large enough data set that is very diverse yet specific to a domain of my interest.
I hope to create a generalized pre-trained weight file that is specific to a domain of my interest.

I know I just can't train and save the model weights since the number of classes would not match (thus the number of layer) between generated pre-trained weight file and the network I am trying to use that pre-trained weight.

I could not find any information regarding creating custom pre-trained weight file on the internet, so any tips or advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your model for training on your data set, the head of it should be a global pooling layer followed by one dense layer. The dense layer will be used to classify based on your data set. Once your model finishes training, you can create a different model that is based on the graph of your trained model but not including the head of it. Then, you can save the weights of this new model which can be used for transfer learning. Below is a simplified view of what I am explaining using Tensorflow's functional API.

```
inputs = Input(shape)
# All hidden layers
x = (...)(inputs)
# Final pooling layer
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# Prediction layer
x = Dense(num_classes)(x)

model = Model(inputs, x)
```

Once you train this model, create a different one connecting all but the head and save the weights.

```
new_model = Model(inputs, model.layers[-2])
new_model.save_weights(file_path)
```

This new model contains the same input as the previous model, but the output is the layer right before the `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` layer.